# Error in Integration of special functions using mathematica 12.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

When I try to integrate the following,

```
Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22,-1/2,x]/(1+k*x),{x,-1,1}]
```

where -1<k<1 and k!=0, Mathematica gives different results if I specify k before hand or  after integrating the expression. Why does this happen ? Somehow, the  result is also different, if I multiply and divide the  expression by (say) 100. I feel like this must be some issue with accuracy or data size, but can someone please explain what I can do to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Can you share your results and a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I just ran the aforementioned line with k=0.2  before and after integrating and got 262144. and 458752.  respectively (I think both are wrong as the result should be close to 0)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a matter of precision. You are looking at high order polynomials.
I don't see the issue connected with fixing k before or after integration:

```
t1 = Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22, -1/2, x]/(1 + k*x), {x, -1, 1}];
k = 1/2; t2 =Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22, -1/2, x]/(1 + k*x), {x, -1, 1}];
k =.;N[(t1 /. k -> 1/2) - t2, 20]
(* 0.*10^-59*)
```

When you evaluate the integral t1 you should use increased WorkingPrecision. Compare

```
Plot[t1, {k, -1., 1.}, PlotRange -> {-.0001, 0}]
```

with

```
Plot[t1, {k, -1., 1.}, WorkingPrecision -> 20,PlotRange -> {-.0001, 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it out. It seems like the value is 0  throughout the domain. This sounds right. When i try to analytically integrate, i get a conditional expression. Is there any way to get that to evaluate to 0 using some precision  arguement as well ? (i dont  think we can specify  working precision for Integrate, and Nintegrate does not converge even with precision of 20)

Comment: @daveSmith the integral is not zero, as you can see `Plot[t1, {k, .8, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[k_] = Assuming[-1 < k < 1 && k != 0, 
   Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22, -1/2, x]/(1 + k*x), {x, -1, 1}]];
```

To test equality of assigning values to `k` before and after the integration

```
test[k_] := 
 int[k] == Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22, -1/2, x]/(1 + k*x), {x, -1, 1}]

test2[k_] := 
 int[k] - Integrate[-GegenbauerC[22, -1/2, x]/(1 + k*x), {x, -1, 1}]

test /@ Range[-9/10, 9/10, 1/5]

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200}, 
 test2 /@ Range[-9/10, 9/10, 1/5] // N[#, 10] &]
```

[image]

Using machine precision can cause problems

```
test[0.1]

(* False *)

test2[0.1]

(* 3.43597*10^10 *)
```

However, for the same value even with relatively low arbitrary - precision

```
test[0.1`10]

(* True *)

test2[0.1`10]

(* 0.*10^22 *)
```

Consequently, don't use machine precision.

```
Plot[int[k], {k, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[int[k], {k, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

[image]

The integral is small but non-zero in the interval

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
  int /@ Range[-9/10, 9/10, 1/5] // N[#, 100] & // N] // Quiet

(* {-8.7837*10^-7, -1.61377*10^-10, -3.40942*10^-14, -4.85371*10^-19, \
-9.0857*10^-29, -9.0857*10^-29, -4.85371*10^-19, -3.40942*10^-14, \
-1.61377*10^-10, -8.7837*10^-7} *)

LogPlot[Abs[int[k]], {k, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]